# Trying to list filtered subscriptions from REST API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to display a subscription from Azure API Management's REST API. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/list#uri-parameters), I should be able to specify a `$filter` parameter in the query string however it's not clear to me what format the filter string should be in and the examples are thin to say the least.

Here is my code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", _azureApiManagementFunctions.CreateSharedAccessToken());
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/json"));

    string filter = "ownerId eq " + "/users/" + user.Id; //this is likely where the issue is

    response = await client.GetAsync("/subscriptions" + "?api-version=" + apiVersion + "&$filter=" + filter);
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var contentsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApimSubscription>(contents);
};
```

I get back an error:

`"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ValidationError\",\"message\":\"Invalid filter clause specified: 'ownerId eq /users/[removed]'.\",\"details\":null}}"`

I also tried setting the filter to `"ownerId eq " + user.userId`.

So my question is, has anyone used the filter parameter like this before and do you have suggestions on how I can obtain the subscription(s) for a single user?

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo in your question, but you wrote `fitler` instead of `filter` in your API resource string...

Comment: Thanks @oerkelens. Updated. Now getting a filter error.

Comment: Based on the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/filter-syntax) I wonder what `/users/` is doing in your filter. What happens if you just use `$"ownerId eq {user.Id}"` or `$"ownerId eq '{user.Id}'"`?

Comment: Thanks. Same resulting error.

Comment: I want to get a password of the user with the response object using this API, can you please help me with the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
string filter = "ownerId eq " + user.Id; 
01.May I know, How you are getting user ID. 
02.Can you debug and send the complete URL that is getting fail ?

Comment: That worked. For some reason my previous test of this failed but I think to was related to another problem.

Comment: Hello Inzi, I want to get the password with the user object from this API, please help me to get the password of users.

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

> $filter=contains(properties/ownerId, 'users/1')

- Base on inspecting Azure Portal UI requests
- In  **Step 18** is your code with the modification
- Skip to step 3 , if your have a service created before

### Step 1 : create

- open https://portal.azure.com then :

[image]

### Step 2 : fill

[image]

- wait 15m to 60m

### Step 3 : open resources

[image]

### Step 4 : open subscription

[image]

### Step 5 : open developers tools

[image]

- then go to the **Network tap before next step**
- or the request will not be recored

### Step 6 : filter

[image]

### Step 7 : inspect the request

[image]

### Step 8 : copy the x-ms-path-query

- text will be like this

> /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/stackoverflow54171031-AMS-ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/stackoverflow54171031-AMS-Name/subscriptions?api-version=2018-01-01&$filter=((contains(properties/displayName,%20'jason-shave-msft')%20or%20contains(properties/stateComment,%20'jason-shave-msft')%20or%20contains(properties/userId,%20'jason-shave-msft')%20or%20contains(properties/productId,%20'jason-shave-msft')))%20and%20(properties/productId%20eq%20'starter')&$top=10

### Step 9 : Decode the URL

- I used https://www.url-encode-decode.com/
- text will be like this

> /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
>   resourceGroups/stackoverflow54171031-AMS-ResourceGroup/
>   providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/
>   service/stackoverflow54171031-AMS-Name/
>   subscriptions?
>   api-version=2018-01-01&
>   $filter=(
>   (contains(properties/displayName, 'jason-shave-msft') or 
>   contains(properties/stateComment, 'jason-shave-msft') or 
>   contains(properties/userId, 'jason-shave-msft') or 
>   contains(properties/productId, 'jason-shave-msft'))
>   ) and (properties/productId eq 'starter')&$top=10

### Step 10 : format the $filter parameter

- text will be like this

  ```
  $filter=
      (
          (
          contains(properties/displayName, 'jason-shave-msft') or 
          contains(properties/stateComment, 'jason-shave-msft') or 
          contains(properties/userId, 'jason-shave-msft') or 
          contains(properties/productId, 'jason-shave-msft')
          )
      ) 
      and 
      (
          properties/productId eq 'starter'
      )
  ```

### Step 11 : open the documentation

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/list

### Step 12 : click try

[image]

### Step 13 : login

- enter your azure email

### Step 14 : choese

[image]

### Step 15 : enter parameters and try without filter

[image]

- see the results down

### Step 16 : enter the filter and try

[image]

### Step 17 :  c# sample

```
      var userid = 1;

      var filter_ownerId = 
               $"contains(properties/ownerId, 'users/{userid}')";

      var filter = $"$filter={filter_ownerId}";

      Console.WriteLine(filter);
```

- will output

  > $filter=contains(properties/ownerId, 'users/1')
- try here https://dotnetfiddle.net/SnFrVV

### Step 18 :  your app code

```
var  subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var  resourceGroupName = "stackoverflow000000-AMS-ResourceGroup";
var  serviceName = "stackoverflow000000-AMS-Name";
var baseUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}"

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", _azureApiManagementFunctions.CreateSharedAccessToken());
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/json"));

    var filter = $"contains(properties/ownerId, 'users/{user.Id}')";

    response = await client.GetAsync($"/subscriptions?api-version={apiVersion}&$filter={filter}");
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var contentsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApimSubscription>(contents);
};
```

Comment: I get the same result. I know the "ownerId" (userId) value and have been trying that in the REST API "try it" sample as you've shown however no variation of what I'm using, or your example works.

Comment: @JasonShave-MSFT do you get results without filter ?

Comment: Yes, I believe I mentioned this in my original post. Also, to test the API I for the given data I want I would only need steps to determine the userId (guid) which can be easily found in the Azure management console under subscriptions. The ownerId is listed there in the path in the table. I appreciate all the outlining steps but you can probably omit 99% of it.

Comment: did you try Step 16 ? get all result and then get a user id , now try again step 16 and replace the (1) with userid

Comment: do still need help ? we can go to chat

Answer (score 0):

Check what API version are you using. Documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/subscription/list#subscriptioncontract specifies Subscription contract for API version 2018-06-01-preview (it's on top of the page). The actual API specs are located here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification/apimanagement/resource-manager/Microsoft.ApiManagement.

Last stable version - 2018-01-01 - specifies that Subscription contract has "userId" property and not "ownerId". The latter has replaced "userId" in preview version and will retain it's place in next stable version.

So if you're using version lower than 2018-06-01-preview use $filter=userId eq '/users/XXX' to filter subscriptions by user. Or for that particular case you could use a different endpoint as well - /users/XXX/subscriptions